# Php Regexp for my case

Tags: php, regex

I want to create a regular expression in php to make sure string is of one of following format :

- integer only example: 1122
- integer,integer example: 88,99
- integer,integer,integer example: 88,99,19

can anyone help me, not able to think any.

Comment: Are our parsing Currency?

Comment: I can see that the question has been already accepted. But for the future you can visit http://regex101.com/. That site will help you out with other regular expressions. Also you can test Tom's and cryptic's proposals and see their explanations (broken down to groups etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(\d+,)*\d+$/
```

This will match any string that is an integer or a list of integers separated by a comma.

```
$var = '12'; // allow
//$var = '12,13'; // allow
//$var = '12,13,13'; // allow
//$var = 'aaa12,13,13fff'; // won't allow
//$var = '12,13,13,11'; // allow

if (preg_match('/^(\d+,)*\d+$/', $var))
{
    echo 'correct';
}
else
{
    echo 'wrong';
}
```

Comment: hey i wont it to limit it three  , i want no limit just the expression

Comment: @PrishtiKapoor your question was not clear, but above now will allow 11,22,33,44,55 and so on.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest regexp for that would be `\d+(,\d+)*`

- `\d+` - matches digits from 0 - 9
- `(,\d+)*` - matches comma and (as above) digits from 0 - 9. * says that there might be 0 or more occurrences

If you need limit to 3 repetitions then this would work fine: `\d+(,\d+){0,2}`

- `(,\d+){0,2}` - matches comma and (as above) digits from 0 - 9. {0,2} says that there might be 2 occurrences at most (bear in mind that the first `\d+` will match first integer)

**EDIT**

The problem you described in comments is that the PHP function which is used performs a search instead of full match.

> `preg_match` - **Searches** subject for a match to the regular
>   expression given in pattern.

So the regular expression is fine. However for `preg_match` function it should be

- `preg_match('/^\d+(,\d+)*$/')` - first regexp
- `preg_match('/^\d+(,\d+){0,2}$/')` - second regexp

`^` to match beginning of your sting (subject) and `$` to match end of your string.

Comment: seems best but what is the php command for this

Comment: i am sorry this is not working 
$var = 'aaa12,13,13fff'; var_dump(preg_match('/\d+(,\d+){0,2}/', $var)); this giving output as 1